# Http basic authentication using ldap credentials in spring security(spring-boot project) to secure rest service calls

Tags: spring-security, ldap, basic-authentication, spring-boot

Using Spring Security
Basic authentication setup works against some hardcoded username passwords as shown here:

http://thoughtfulsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/adding-security-to-spring-guides-rest-service/

So trying to extend it to use LDAP.

Completed the set up for LDAP authentication with our LDAP server

Now when I try to call my rest service through REST Console plug-in an authorization window keeps on popping up for username password. If I cancel it authorization fails, not sure where I am going wrong

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic();


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})").userSearchBase("ou=people,dc=zzz,dc=xxxx,dc=yyy")
            .groupRoleAttribute("cn").groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
                //.userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                //.groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource().url("ldaps://ldap.xxxx.yyy:636/cn=cw-grpreader,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx")
                .managerDn("cn=xx-xxr,ou=people,dc=med,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx")
                .managerPassword("#$%^^");
    }
```

This is one way I tried which give the recurring authentication popup
if I cancel the popup I get
HTTP Status 401 - [LDAP: error code 49 - NDS error: failed authentication (-669)]; error even if the credentials are correct
Link to some tutorial will be really helpful

Comment: Post your configuration.

Comment: Sounds like it's working. Can you type your ldap credentials into the dialog and authenticate? (Post your configuration.)

Comment: @Dave I am putting in the credentials but its coming back
Adding the configuration

Comment: At least it looks like you are connecting to the server. Did you test the url and DN separately? I suspect it's just the LDAP configuration that's wrong (although I would recommend pulling it out into a separate `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`).

Comment: @Dave I am now using the GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter as suggested. It seems the httpbasic authentication is still failing to go against the LDAP service for authentication 


(HTTP Status 401 - Bad credentials with status report This request requires HTTP authentication)

Comment: I would recommend switching on DEBUG logging for Spring Security.

Comment: @Dave I figured out it was the configuration problem. Strangely the recurring popup for authentication does not come anymore, and I am not able to reproduce it!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to httpbasic authentication that you have set up.  Spring boot generates a random password thats shown on console which you could use.

To disable that pop-up simply add this to your application.properties file.

```
security.basic.enabled: false
```